# JavaScript - check if data id equals function parameter

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I check the id of data from database with function parameter

### Here is my script

```
 function parametr(id) {
        $.post( "/db.php", { id: id }, function( data ) {            
            $("div#displayinfoid").html( data );
            console.log('TEST');
        });
    }
```

### Here I am getting img id for database

```
<a class="pic" href="#">
 <img onload="parametr('5');" src="west.jpg"/></a>
```

### This displays info from databse

```
<div id="displayinfoid">
```

---

And the joke is if in the database there are 10 records html file displays one record for 10

. So I wanna specify each record for each list

Answer (score 0):

`html()` will replace the whole content of a node.
use `$("div#displayinfoid").append( data );` instead of `html( data )`